# Using global validation in Strut2

Tags: struts2

In struts2, I want to validate address 1 input value on 4 different pages. I dont want to copy the regex in 4 different `action_name-validation.xml`. Can I create a global `validation.xml` where I can define a variable and is use it in other `action_name-validation.xml` files? Please provide an example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use annotations, you may wish to consider creating a custom validator for your address line and use that where needed. Example code can be found via google, for example, http://java-x.blogspot.com/2008/04/struts-2-custom-validators.html

Answer (score 0):

Not have a much experience in validation framework, but as per little i know about that `Validation` rules are handled by `validators` in validation framework.All you need to do is to registered your `validation` with the `ValidatorFactory`.

The simplest way to do so is to add a file name `validators.xml` in the root of the `classpath` `(/WEB-INF/classes)` that declares all the validators you intend to use.

You can find more details at the official documentation.

[Validation framework Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/validation.html#Validation-RegisteringValidators)